# Cant find an error in my program (Android Programming)

Tags: java, android

The buttons is not working at all, results below. Ignore the comments in the code :). I've copy/pasted the important parts of the XML needed to shorten how long this question is.

Screenshot of the app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM8N5.png

It doesn't work when I hit the "compute" button also the Send Orders button doesn't work either.

XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCheese"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblCheese"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtHam"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtHam"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtHam"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtHam" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtFries"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblFries"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtCheese"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtCheese"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtCheese"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtCheese" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtDrinks"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblDrinks"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtFries"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtFries"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtFries"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtFries" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Compute"
    android:id="@+id/btnCompute"
    android:onClick="doCompute"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDrinks"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/proDrinks"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/proDrinks"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Orders"
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:onClick="doSend"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCompute"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

JAVA

```
package com.example.administrator.jollymangdonald;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnCompute, btnSend;
EditText txtHam, txtCheese, txtFries, txtDrinks;
TextView lblHam, lblCheese, lblFries, lblDrinks, lblHam2, lblCheese2, lblFries2, lblDrinks2, lblTotal, productHam, productCheese, productFries, productDrinks, Total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnCompute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCompute);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    txtHam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHam);
    txtCheese = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCheese);
    txtFries = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFries);
    txtDrinks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDrinks);

    lblTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTotal);
    lblHam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblHam);
    lblCheese = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCheese);
    lblFries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFries);
    lblDrinks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDrinks);

    lblHam2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblHam2);
    lblCheese2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCheese2);
    lblFries2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFries2);
    lblDrinks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDrinks);

    productHam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proHam);
    productCheese = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proCheese);
    productFries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proFries);
    productDrinks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proDrinks);


    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendSMSMessage();
        }
    });
    btnCompute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doCompute();
        }
    });}



public void doCompute(){

    int lblHam = 25;
    int lblCheese = 35;
    int lblFries = 25;
    int lblDrinks = 20;

    int Total;

    int HamQ = Integer.valueOf(txtHam.getText().toString()); // unnecessary .toString(), getText() already returns string, Oops, editable pala return, sorry, haha
    int CheeseQ = Integer.valueOf(txtCheese.getText().toString());
    int FriesQ = Integer.valueOf(txtFries.getText().toString());
    int DrinksQ = Integer.valueOf(txtDrinks.getText().toString());

    int HamSub;
    int CheeseSub;
    int FriesSub;
    int DrinksSub;

    HamSub = lblHam * HamQ;
    CheeseSub = lblCheese * CheeseQ;
    FriesSub = lblFries * FriesQ;
    DrinksSub = lblDrinks * DrinksQ;

    lblHam2.setText(HamSub + ""); // you can also do it this way, much more concise
    lblCheese2.setText(Integer.toString(CheeseSub));
    lblFries2.setText(Integer.toString(FriesSub));
    lblDrinks2.setText(Integer.toString(FriesSub));

    Total = HamSub + CheeseSub + FriesSub + DrinksSub;

    lblTotal.setText(Integer.toString(Total));
}

public void SendSMSMessage(){
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
    String phoneNo = "example phone number";
    String msg =  productHam.getText().toString() + " " + txtHam.getText().toString() + " " + lblHam2.getText().toString() + "\n" + productCheese.getText().toString() + " " +
            txtCheese.getText().toString() + "  " + lblCheese2.getText().toString() + "\n" + productFries.getText().toString() + " " + txtFries.getText().toString() + " " + lblFries2.getText().toString() + "\n" +
            productDrinks.getText().toString() + " " + txtDrinks.getText().toString() + " " + lblDrinks2.getText().toString() + "\n" + lblTotal.getText().toString();

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Failed, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Errors:
For compute: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWTj7.png
For Send Orders: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkQbD.png

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: Can you tell us what line 96 and line 108 is? Those are the locations where you exception occurs.

Comment: I tried but I can't find it

Comment: line 96= showing the subtotal and the total (in the textview, just next to the sendorders button) after clicking the "compute" button and filling the quantities needed

line 108= sending send sms orders by getting the results from the results of subtotal, total, product names and quantities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `lblDrinks2` is never initialized.

As shown by the first screenshot, you try to call a method on `lbDrinks2` which is null (line 96):

```
public void doCompute(){
    // ...
    lblDrinks2.setText(Integer.toString(FriesSub));
    // ...
}
```

It's the same problem here (line 108):

```
public void SendSMSMessage(){
    // ...
    productDrinks.getText().toString() + " " + txtDrinks.getText().toString() + " " + lblDrinks2.getText().toString() + "\n" + lblTotal.getText().toString();
    // ...
}
```

Try to initialize it in the `onCreate` method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    lblDrinks2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDrinks2); // if R.id.lblDrinks2 exists 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! from now on, im going to focus my eyes in my codes :(

lbldrinks was duplicated from the oncreate thats why im getting errors 
it should be lbldrinks and lbldrinks2 in the oncreate method :) THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You're welcome, just don't forget to close the question :) Small advice for next time, try to put a break point at the line where the error is thrown, and evaluate it at runtime. This will help you to investigate the problem.